# Is there an equivalent of Bootstrap to make a single page application look like a native mobile app for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

My app works fine on a laptop, but on an iphone the size of tables, use of modals, and general layout of the app looks a bit crappy (even with bootstrap and its responsive layout). There's just too much info on one page, and it would be better to have it appear more like a native app (but without the hassle of writing one and configuring the Rails API to talk to it).

I know I could rip out all my Controller/View code and built a js framework front end, but I was wondering whether there's anything similar to Bootstrap that I could use instead - ideally just taking some template CSS/JS and then re-writing the HTML views if a request comes in from a phone/tablet?

Does this exist, or am I going to have to bite the bullet and learn e.g. Ember.js?

Comment: You can use Bootstrap and make your app appear "native".  Sounds like you have issues with what you do with the framework and not the actual framework.  There are other frameworks like jQuery Mobile, Zerb Foundation 6, Sencha, and many others.  How extensively you would have to change your app in order to migrate to single page app -- depends on your current app, of course.  But you may want to do more research and figure out if SPA is the right way to go for you.  Its not always the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Technically mine is slightly more than a SPA, but there are only a few pages, and each page behaves like an SPA in its own right. The functionality works well and looks good on a laptop (primary use-case), but on mobile the amount of info displayed is just too much. It would be better to have panels that a user clicks on to show each individual page feature - much more like a native app.